# Data not correctly read from file using >> operator

Tags: c++

I have a data file with 3 columns in each row: Two 3 character strings and a float like this.

```
AAA BBB 699.25
```

I'm trying to read in the data using ifstream like this:

```
    ifstream input;

    char str1[3], str2[3];
    float num;

    input.open("data.txt");

    input >> str1 >> str2 >> num;
    cout << str1 << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl;
    cout << num << endl;
```

However the output I get with Clang is:

```
(blank)
BBB
699.25
```

Or Intel C++ this:

```
AAABBB
BBB
699.25
```

If I get the individual variables without multiple ">>" operators all works correctly. I'm guessing I don't understand how >> works and it's overwriting my data in the buffer as I push more into the array.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using such ridiculously small buffers? Two characters plus a `NULL` is not a lot of room.

Comment: @tadman I'm pretty new to C++ so I figured I would use the exact size I needed without thinking of any hidden characters. Problem solved.

Comment: There is no "exact size needed" when reading from `stdin`. You have *zero* control over what's coming in, so it could be two bytes, or two gigabytes. Use `std::string`. Fixed sized buffers will almost always bite you hard. Don't use them unless you literally have no other choice.

Comment: Weird... `operator>>` returns an `istream&`, which the same object as the one it's called on so there should  be no difference (by the standard). But as @tadman said, you simply do not allocate enough memory to store your input.

Comment: Safe and correct programs are more important than saving a few bytes. If you are new I suggest you use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of arrays. It will save you so much pain.

Answer (score 7):

The string `"AAA"` is not three characters long.  You have three visible characters and one non visible null character.  This means to hold `"AAA"` you need four characters worth of storage.  If you use a `std::string` this becomes a non issue as it takes care of things like this for you.  Since you just have this tagged as C++ I would change `char str1[3], str2[3];` to `std::string str1, str2;`